# Compiling c++ in Sublime Text 3 with MinGW under win 10

Tags: c++, mingw, sublimetext3

I have installed all necessary add-on as mentioned by others. When I compile the cpp file with MinGW (using `ctrl-shift-b` and choose `MinGW` or `Run::MinGW`)

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       cout<<"Hello world !"<<endl;
       return 0;
    }
```

a system error occurs with statement

[image]

the configuration file for `MinGW` is set as follows:

[image]

the path is correctly set. So what's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `g++` instead of `gcc`, you're missing the C++ Standard library, which results in "undefined references" which just means you're not linking the compiled definitions of the things you're using in the code.